# Converting msg.value in other solidity units

Tags: contract-development

In my app, I need to check if the value received in a payable function is equal or greater than a fixed number (priceToSell) expressed in finney. What is the best way to check that? Is that?

require (msg.value/(1 finney) >= priceToSell);

Thank you

Comment: How about `require (msg.value >= priceToSell * (1 finney));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be correct, but there are a few things to note.

1. When doing any sort of arithmetic, it is highly advised that you use something like OpenZeppelin's SafeMath library to avoid over/underflows. Your existing code would be

   `require(msg.value.div(1 finney) >= priceToSell);`
2. Be sure to account for units. If you are dealing in finney, then what you have works.
3. Since there are no floats in solidity, a div could result in an unexpected number. For example, `11/10 = 1` in Solidity. Make sure you account for the extreme values of contribution (both max and min)

Comment: No integer underflow or overflow is possible when doing division in Solidity. All [SafeMath.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) does for division is revert instead of assert when the divisor is 0. There's no security risk of not using it here. (I don't disagree that it's a general best practice, but I disagree that it's worth mentioning about this code.)

Comment: You are correct.